# html - set the horizontal scrollbar when browser is shrink

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get that my web page appears a horizontal scrollbar when the user shrink his/her browser, but instead everything is getting shrink, but that's not the way I would like, I have try it a lot of things (such as overflow-y etc.) here is my website (try to resize it):
http://prepaestatal9.site11.com/news.php
here is the html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title></title>

        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico">
        <link href="styleregistration.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>



<body>

     <div id="mainBlank">

         <h1 style="text-align: center;">Noticias</h1>

        <div id="refresh"><table style="width:50%;"><tr><td colspan='2' style='background-color:#f96267;'>no se</td></tr><tr><td style='background-color:#bde0e4;'>no  importa</td> <td style='background-color:#bde0e4;'>2014-01-02 19:22:38</td></tr><tr><td colspan='2' style='background-color:#885878; text-align:center;'>nueva noticia<br />
no hay clase</td></tr><tr style='height:40px; border-left:none;'></tr><tr><td colspan='2' style='background-color:#f96267;'>yoooo</td></tr><tr><td style='background-color:#bde0e4;'>dssd</td> <td style='background-color:#bde0e4;'>2014-01-02 19:16:39</td></tr><tr><td colspan='2' style='background-color:#885878; text-align:center;'>ds<br />
ds</td></tr><tr style='height:40px; border-left:none;'></tr><tr><td colspan='2' style='background-color:#f96267;'>hih</td></tr><tr><td style='background-color:#bde0e4;'>bhj</td> <td style='background-color:#bde0e4;'>2014-01-02 19:16:12</td></tr><tr><td colspan='2' style='background-color:#885878; text-align:center;'>ft<br />
yf<br />
yt</td></tr><tr style='height:40px; border-left:none;'></tr></table></div>            
    </div>


    </body>
</html>
```

a simple table inside a div called mainBlank inside the body

and here is the css code
styleregistration.css

```
@font-face
{
font-family: yano;
src: url(fonts/yano.woff);
}

body {

    width: 100%;
    font-family:yano;
    background-image: url(images/dirtyred.png);
    background-repeat:repeat;
    position:relative;
    margin: 0;
}

#mainBlank{

    border-radius:5px;
    background-image: url(images/word.png);
    -moz-box-shadow:    10px 10px 5px #888888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
    box-shadow:         10px 10px 5px #888888;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 20%;
    margin-top: 15%;
    /*margin-bottom: 1%;*/
    height: 30%;
    color: black;
    padding-top: 1%;
    padding-bottom: 1%;
    padding-left: 1%;
    padding-right: 1%;
}
```

and thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing everything in percentages of the browser size. Your margins left, right, etc and even your height.

It looks alright, but everything is simply going to be a percentage of the browser width. So, when you resize it, everything else will resize as well. No one can really give you specific code, because you are the designer of your website. Try giving your `#mainBlank`

```
width:700px;
margin:auto;
```

and removing all of the margin and padding values. Adjust from there.

Comment: I didn't know that if I use percetages I could be problematic, I have used px instead, and I have resolved it thanks dude

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest trying the solution @Adonis K has provided.

```
overflow-y: scroll
```

forces a **vertical** scroll bar.

That being the the case I would assume that

```
overflow-x: visible
```

could work for **horizontal** although I have not used this (I believe in no Horizontal scroll bars due to aesthetics)

If that doesn't work try

```
overflow-x: scroll
```

or alternatively

```
html {
overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

or

```
html {
overflow-x: visible;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use overflow-x for that:

```
#mainBlank {
    overflow-x: visible;
}
```

"The overflow CSS property specifies whether to clip content, render scroll bars or display overflow content of a block-level element."

[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) | [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Vv85t/2/)

---

Another solution is to use a static width like @smts mentions but instead of just a static value you could use something like this:

```
#mainBlank {
    width: 700px;
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

This way, if the width of the element is larger than the width of the screen, then it will shrink down to the screen's maximum width.